# how can i remove user folder from url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I rewrite the URL `www.example.com/user/xxxx` into `www.example.com/xxxx` using `htaccess` ?

I tried:

```
 Redirect /user / user/xxx
```

But, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)  / user/$1
```